# Android, how to change splash screen for 18.5:9,16:9

Tags: android-layout, titanium

I have splash screen directory like this below.

I tested on Galaxy Note 8 which has 1440 x 2960 resolution,
but, 1440 x 2960 is not selected and splash screen is streched vertically.

It's quite confusing to sort out, what resolution for what dpi.

What if there are two ratio like 16:9, 18.5:9 on the same xxhdpi???
How is the best practice??

```
Resources/android/images/res-long-port-hdpi/default.png (480 x 800)
Resources/android/images/res-long-port-ldpi/default.png (240 x 400)
Resources/android/images/res-long-port-xhdpi/default.png (640 x 960)
Resources/android/images/res-long-port-xxhdpi/default.png (1080 x 1920)
Resources/android/images/res-long-port-xxxhdpi/default.png (1440 x 2960)

Resources/android/images/res-notlong-port-hdpi/default.png (480x 800)
Resources/android/images/res-notlong-port-ldpi/default.png (240 x 320)
Resources/android/images/res-notlong-port-mdpi/default.png (320 x 480)
Resources/android/images/res-notlong-port-xhdpi/default.png (640 x 960)
Resources/android/images/res-notlong-port-xxhdpi/default.png (1080 x 1920)
Resources/android/images/res-notlong-port-xxxhdpi/default.png (1440 x 2960)
```

Comment: use 9-patch images as splashes to prevent a huge amount of images

Comment: @Rene Pot It solves my problem thank you very much.